# Query for annotated tag with commit SHA

Tags: git, api, azure-devops

I have a few questions about using DevOps API for annotated tags.
* I need to update tag name for commit and keep its original message
* I need to get annotated tag with its message by using commit SHA

This is needed for automation

Here's the link for API Documentation which didn't really help much
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/annotated%20tags/create?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0

This is how you can delete an annotated tag
https://.visualstudio.com//one/_apis/git/repositories//refs?api-version=5.0-preview.1

```
body
[
{
    "name":  "refs/tags/<tag name>",
    "newObjectId":  "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "oldObjectId":  <current tag's  SHA1>
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to update tag name for commit and keep its original message.

For this demand , I am afraid it is not feasible in azure devops with rest api . The tag added to the commit is not editable.There is no option to modify the tag in the UI interface, so the api also can't be captured from the page.

You can raise your feature demand [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) to promote development of richer features

After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.